# metric-server crashloopbackoff - Error: Unauthorized

Tags: kubernetes

I deploy a k8s+rook cluster using kubespray, and I´m not able to run the metrics-server pod, it gets to crashloopbackoff error. Running "kubectl get pods -n kube-system" I see the following output:

```
kubectl get pods,svc,deployments --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=metrics-server 
NAME                                  READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/metrics-server-6d457b757f-hztqt   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   13         45m

NAME                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/metrics-server   0/1     1            0           60m
```

Then, running "kubectl describe pods metrics-server -n kube-system" I see the following:

```
Name:         metrics-server-6d457b757f-hztqt
Namespace:    kube-system
Priority:     0
Node:         kubeslave01.mendoza.gov.ar/192.168.129.145
Start Time:   Sat, 11 Apr 2020 01:51:27 -0300
Labels:       k8s-app=metrics-server
              pod-template-hash=6d457b757f
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.129.145
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.129.145
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/metrics-server-6d457b757f
Containers:
  metrics-server:
    Container ID:  docker://4fac9ba94e554aa2ff46858790cbe4287801fd22771bb5f327aa742e5513ed85
    Image:         k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.6
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64@sha256:c9c4e95068b51d6b33a9dccc61875df07dc650abbf4ac1a19d58b4628f89288b
    Port:          4443/TCP
    Host Port:     4443/TCP
    Args:
      --cert-dir=/tmp
      --kubelet-insecure-tls
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
      --metric-resolution=30s
      --secure-port=4443
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Sat, 11 Apr 2020 02:33:03 -0300
      Finished:     Sat, 11 Apr 2020 02:33:04 -0300
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  13
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /tmp from tmp-dir (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from metrics-server-token-2c82b (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  tmp-dir:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:     
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  metrics-server-token-2c82b:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  metrics-server-token-2c82b
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                 kubernetes.io/os=linux
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From                                 Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----                                 -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>            default-scheduler                    Successfully assigned kube-system/metrics-server-6d457b757f-hztqt to kubeslave01.mendoza.gov.ar
  Normal   Pulled     44m (x5 over 45m)    kubelet, kubeslave01.mendoza.gov.ar  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/metrics-server-amd64:v0.3.6" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    44m (x5 over 45m)    kubelet, kubeslave01.mendoza.gov.ar  Created container metrics-server
  Normal   Started    44m (x5 over 45m)    kubelet, kubeslave01.mendoza.gov.ar  Started container metrics-server
  Warning  BackOff    49s (x205 over 45m)  kubelet, kubeslave01.mendoza.gov.ar  Back-off restarting failed container
```

The logs output "kubectl logs pod/metrics-server-6d457b757f-hztqt -n kube-system" basically says  Error: Unauthorized

```
Error: Unauthorized
Usage:
   [flags]

Flags:
      --alsologtostderr                                         log to standard error as well as files
      --authentication-kubeconfig string                        kubeconfig file pointing at the 'core' kubernetes server with enough rights to create tokenaccessreviews.authentication.k8s.io.
      --authentication-skip-lookup                              If false, the authentication-kubeconfig will be used to lookup missing authentication configuration from the cluster.
      --authentication-token-webhook-cache-ttl duration         The duration to cache responses from the webhook token authenticator. (default 10s)
      --authentication-tolerate-lookup-failure                  If true, failures to look up missing authentication configuration from the cluster are not considered fatal. Note that this can result in authentication that treats all requests as anonymous.
      --authorization-always-allow-paths strings                A list of HTTP paths to skip during authorization, i.e. these are authorized without contacting the 'core' kubernetes server.
      --authorization-kubeconfig string                         kubeconfig file pointing at the 'core' kubernetes server with enough rights to create subjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io.
      --authorization-webhook-cache-authorized-ttl duration     The duration to cache 'authorized' responses from the webhook authorizer. (default 10s)
      --authorization-webhook-cache-unauthorized-ttl duration   The duration to cache 'unauthorized' responses from the webhook authorizer. (default 10s)
      --bind-address ip                                         The IP address on which to listen for the --secure-port port. The associated interface(s) must be reachable by the rest of the cluster, and by CLI/web clients. If blank, all interfaces will be used (0.0.0.0 for all IPv4 interfaces and :: for all IPv6 interfaces). (default 0.0.0.0)
      --cert-dir string                                         The directory where the TLS certs are located. If --tls-cert-file and --tls-private-key-file are provided, this flag will be ignored. (default "apiserver.local.config/certificates")
      --client-ca-file string                                   If set, any request presenting a client certificate signed by one of the authorities in the client-ca-file is authenticated with an identity corresponding to the CommonName of the client certificate.
      --contention-profiling                                    Enable lock contention profiling, if profiling is enabled
  -h, --help                                                    help for this command
      --http2-max-streams-per-connection int                    The limit that the server gives to clients for the maximum number of streams in an HTTP/2 connection. Zero means to use golang's default.
      --kubeconfig string                                       The path to the kubeconfig used to connect to the Kubernetes API server and the Kubelets (defaults to in-cluster config)
      --kubelet-certificate-authority string                    Path to the CA to use to validate the Kubelet's serving certificates.
      --kubelet-insecure-tls                                    Do not verify CA of serving certificates presented by Kubelets.  For testing purposes only.
      --kubelet-port int                                        The port to use to connect to Kubelets. (default 10250)
      --kubelet-preferred-address-types strings                 The priority of node address types to use when determining which address to use to connect to a particular node (default [Hostname,InternalDNS,InternalIP,ExternalDNS,ExternalIP])
      --log-flush-frequency duration                            Maximum number of seconds between log flushes (default 5s)
      --log_backtrace_at traceLocation                          when logging hits line file:N, emit a stack trace (default :0)
      --log_dir string                                          If non-empty, write log files in this directory
      --log_file string                                         If non-empty, use this log file
      --logtostderr                                             log to standard error instead of files (default true)
      --metric-resolution duration                              The resolution at which metrics-server will retain metrics. (default 1m0s)
      --profiling                                               Enable profiling via web interface host:port/debug/pprof/ (default true)
      --requestheader-allowed-names strings                     List of client certificate common names to allow to provide usernames in headers specified by --requestheader-username-headers. If empty, any client certificate validated by the authorities in --requestheader-client-ca-file is allowed.
      --requestheader-client-ca-file string                     Root certificate bundle to use to verify client certificates on incoming requests before trusting usernames in headers specified by --requestheader-username-headers. WARNING: generally do not depend on authorization being already done for incoming requests.
      --requestheader-extra-headers-prefix strings              List of request header prefixes to inspect. X-Remote-Extra- is suggested. (default [x-remote-extra-])
      --requestheader-group-headers strings                     List of request headers to inspect for groups. X-Remote-Group is suggested. (default [x-remote-group])
      --requestheader-username-headers strings                  List of request headers to inspect for usernames. X-Remote-User is common. (default [x-remote-user])
      --secure-port int                                         The port on which to serve HTTPS with authentication and authorization.If 0, don't serve HTTPS at all. (default 443)
      --skip_headers                                            If true, avoid header prefixes in the log messages
      --stderrthreshold severity                                logs at or above this threshold go to stderr
      --tls-cert-file string                                    File containing the default x509 Certificate for HTTPS. (CA cert, if any, concatenated after server cert). If HTTPS serving is enabled, and --tls-cert-file and --tls-private-key-file are not provided, a self-signed certificate and key are generated for the public address and saved to the directory specified by --cert-dir.
      --tls-cipher-suites strings                               Comma-separated list of cipher suites for the server. If omitted, the default Go cipher suites will be use.  Possible values: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
      --tls-min-version string                                  Minimum TLS version supported. Possible values: VersionTLS10, VersionTLS11, VersionTLS12
      --tls-private-key-file string                             File containing the default x509 private key matching --tls-cert-file.
      --tls-sni-cert-key namedCertKey                           A pair of x509 certificate and private key file paths, optionally suffixed with a list of domain patterns which are fully qualified domain names, possibly with prefixed wildcard segments. If no domain patterns are provided, the names of the certificate are extracted. Non-wildcard matches trump over wildcard matches, explicit domain patterns trump over extracted names. For multiple key/certificate pairs, use the --tls-sni-cert-key multiple times. Examples: "example.crt,example.key" or "foo.crt,foo.key:*.foo.com,foo.com". (default [])
  -v, --v Level                                                 number for the log level verbosity
      --vmodule moduleSpec                                      comma-separated list of pattern=N settings for file-filtered logging

panic: Unauthorized

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /go/src/github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/cmd/metrics-server/metrics-server.go:39 +0x13b
```

I already try editing and adding this flags to the metric-server instance:

```
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
        - --metric-resolution=30s
```

Can someone help me figuring out what is wrong? I´ve seen a lot of similar cases, but none of them worked.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: share kubelet and Kubernetes API Server logs.which doc you followed to install it? which yaml used? is aggregation layer enabled in the kube API Server? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/configure-aggregation-layer/

Comment: Thanks for your help the error was the aggregation layer disabled. Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kube-apiserver must be correctly configured to enable an aggregation layer.Verify if aggregation layer in kubernetes API server is enabled or not.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/configure-aggregation-layer/